Why isIPAddressInRange doesn't work in JOINs in ClickHouse
I have 2 tables:

ipv4,city_name
ipv4_range,lat,lon - "ipv4_range" has the range of IPs that collapsed using mask - "8.8.8.0/29"

The problem popps out when I'm trying to glue table 2 to table 1:
SELECT
   t1.ipv4, 
   t1.city_name, 
   t2.lat, 
   t2.lon
FROM table_2 t2
   LEFT JOIN table_1 t1 ON isIPAddressInRange(t1.ipv4, t2.ipv4_range) = 1

Error:
DB::Exception: Invalid columns in JOIN ON section. Columns --t1.ipv4 and --t2.ipv4_range are from different tables.: While processing isIPAddressInRange ... = 1. (INVALID_JOIN_ON_EXPRESSION)

Is there any workaround for this issue? I could expand masked IPs into a regular IP addresses, but it's real pain to see how my DB grows from 700MB to 200GB...

You can use CROSS JOIN and then filter out using isIPAddressInRange.
See https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/07d252ec-f94c-4dc2-b0b0-3aeb262e23b2
